# Detect character position in photo

Tags: opencv

This is a very clear image. I want to know the pixel position of character C . I believe OpenCV can be used with thresholding etc, but can someone suggest what should be best mechanism to get C pixel. If there is another technique then please suggest. I doubt if CNN and deep learning can be used, as I dont have much samples.

I had tried following code, but it yielded a lot of blackish image and lot of contours.

```
cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU,img)

contours, hier = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

[image]

Another task I want to do is, to detect is the orientation, whether C is lying vertical or horizontal.

Comment: If you are ok to use a pretrained character detection model, I think you will be able to find an opensource project that serves your purpose.

Comment: thanks... can you please suggest the name

Comment: The background is white and the letter has the same color.. segmentate it is impossible.